# How to get a one-to-many in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list -

A
B
C
D

I'm trying to, with formulas only, create:

A1
A2
B1
B2
C1
C2

Etc.

This has been driving me nuts for months now. I've been trying some combination of arrays, index, and sumproduct, but can't quite get them to work together...

```
{=INDEX(SUMPRODUCT(A1:A5*B1:B2),ROW(A1))}
```

Is the best I've been able to come up with, but it gives me a #VALUE error.

Excel 2010 might be the reason, I know higher versions of excel let you multiple numbers by letters

Comment: How many numbers you need? You only includes 1 and 2 here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your two values are in A and B then put this in the first output cell and copy/drag down:

```
=IF(ROW(1:1)<=COUNTIF(B:B,"<>")*COUNTIF(A:A,"<>"), INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/COUNTIF(B:B,"<>"))+1) & INDEX(B:B,MOD((ROW(1:1)-1),COUNTIF(B:B,"<>"))+1),"")
```

It is dynamic, so copy/drag down a long ways.  Then as the values change in A and B the cells will update.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With letters in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,ROUNDUP(ROW()/2,0)) & MOD(ROW()-1,2)+1
```

and copy down.